# who is interested OR who interest

Tags: grammar

which one of two these sentences is correct?

> I am kind of person who is really interested in doing exercise?
>   I am kind of person who interested in exercise?

I think that be interested in some thing is correct

Answer (score 1):

I am the kind of person who is really interested in doing exercise.

The second half of the sentence requires another verb. Who references person and acts as the subject of the second half of the sentence. You do require the word "the" (or possible "a") before "kind" though, because you are specifying which kind of person you are (*the* kind).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @yuankhan that you definitely need to add the "the".

Your second sentence requires a "the" and an "is".

Your sentence: I am kind of person who interested in exercise.

Sentence should be: I am the kind of person who is interested in exercise.